# How can I pass data from activity to the dialogFragment that activity invoked?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In my application I have a form the user fills in. Pressing "save" the data will be saved to the local database. I want to add a confirm dialog for the user to review the details he entered before moving on, since those details are crucial.

In my dialogFragment instance, I would have something like: "You are entering these details: A,B,C... do you confirm?"

A,B,C are the values of my EditText fields in the activity which calls the dialogFragment

How can I access those values from the dialogFragment? I am using:

```
new ConfirmSaveProjectDetails().show(getFragmentManager(),"Confirm");
```

in my activity. `ConfirmSaveProjectDetails` is my dialogFragment class.

I am not using an Intent, otherwise I would send a Bundle...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add arguments in the form of a bundle into the Fragment and then retrieve them from the fragment. Use the following methods available on a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html):

`setArguments` and `getArguments`.

Passing them as arguments to the Fragments constructor is always an option too.

Comment: `setArgument` still works, but using the constructor to pass arguments now results in this error (Android SDK 21.1): "This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)"

Comment: When you define your own (non-default) constructor you also need to need to define a public default constructor. Under certain circumstances the Fragment will be recreated and the default constructor will get called, after which `onCreate` etc. will get called with a non-null bundle. You would use the bundle to restore any instance data such as that you may have initialised from the data passed into the constructor. IMO using `setArguments` is better as that bundle is serialized out and you just need to call `getArguments` to get that data on Fragment (re-)creation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most pretty/elegant method, but you could make those bits of information `public static` and then reference them from the dialog.

In the activity/fragment where you gather the data:

```
public static String A
public static String B
public static String C
```

And grab it in the dialog fragment like so (apologies if I'm explaining something you already know):

```
your_activity/fragment_classname.A
your_activity/fragment_classname.B
your_activity/fragment_classname.C
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **Activity**

```
ImageViewDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ImageViewDialogFragment ();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("link",moviesList.get(position).getImage());
                        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        dialogFragment.show((GalleryReviewActivity.this).getSupportFragmentManager(),"Image Dialog");
```

in your **DialogFragment**

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();
 String imageLink = bundle.getString("link","");
```